# Adding libPusher to My project or Any sample project in pusher chat app in IOS?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, pusher

I have an Iphone application in which i wanted to use libpusher library.On the way i got this link `https://github.com/lukeredpath/libPusher/wiki/Adding-libPusher-to-your-project`.But still i have left with so many options.And doesnt really explaining which are the methods to call and which are the delegate methodes and purposes.Do anybody has any great tutorial or sample application for achieving this.I am totally new to this API.Can anybody take me out of this dig?

Comment: So the problem is that you have problem to find a tutorial to use it, not to install it?

Comment: Does this should help you? Tell me if it is useful so I can write an answer :) http://lukeredpath.github.com/libPusher/html/index.html

Comment: @MarcoPace this is good .But my question is clear,how we can use these methods to achieve chats or how we can include this methods in our project

Comment: @MarcoPace like the MGTWItterengine we are using ...in that blog it is quite clear that way to do with the methods in our project